# Why is this easier-than-hello-world angularjs application not working?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, plunker

I'm following a pluralsight tutorial to learn angularjs, and I'm already stuck on the first video.

The tutorial uses plunker, here is the [link to my code](http://plnkr.co/edit/ogmlEyLuzX3UBK65qgjk?p=preview)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app>
    <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
    {{ 843 / 42 }}
  </body>

</html>
```

I followed the instructions, clicked the button to add angularjs to my html doc (i.e. it just adds the link in the header and the ng-app to the body tag) but it is not working.

In the video, he types `{{ 843 / 42 }}` and it prints to the page 20.07.... whereas mine is just printing `{{ 843 / 42 }}`.

I can't start learning about angularjs until I figure out why my code is not working, but I can't figure out why my code is not working until I learn more about angularjs...

Comment: Always post the relevant code at SO. Even if you have created plunker or fiddle

Comment: you didn't include `angular.min.js`. see now it worked http://plnkr.co/edit/d9XslN3et6N60nYBYVlj?p=preview

Comment: hmm. so the self-adding script link doesn't work then I guess...

Comment: Give people a real chance to ask for help without being overly judgemental. Easy with the downvotes, @xcdemon05 had a legitimate issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was listening to the same video and I had the same issue. I started by using the latest angular js file.

I then tried to use the same [Angular JS file](https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.0-beta.5/angular.js) he was using and then it worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to add the whole program for someone's help.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.3.0" data-semver="1.3.0"
        src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.0-beta.5/angular.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app>
    {{ 8/4 }}
  </body>

</html>
```